# Unable to create and insert data into a new table in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I'm trying to create and insert values into a table in my resource data.sql file in Spring boot, I get the below error:

```
"Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "SWISSFRANC" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO conversion_value(id,currency_from,currency_to,Conversion_factor,port) VALUES (10001,swissfranc,INR,65,0) [42122-200]"

my data.sql file contains:
INSERT INTO conversion_value(id,currency_from,currency_to,Conversion_factor,port)
VALUES (10001,swissfranc,INR,65,0);

INSERT INTO conversion_value(id,currency_from,currency_to,Conversion_factor,port)
VALUES (10002,euro,INR,75,0);

INSERT INTO conversion_value(id,currency_from,currency_to,Conversion_factor,port)
VALUES (10003,australiandollar,INR,25,0);
```

Comment: is this the complete data.sql file? Can you share the table definition and entities? A better way is to use liquibase unless you want to populate data for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes : `'euro'` or `'swissfranc'`, etc around the values that you insert.
This is a syntax error in your `data.sql` file.
Fixed example:

```
INSERT INTO conversion_value(id,currency_from,currency_to,Conversion_factor,port) VALUES (10001,'swissfranc','INR',65,0);
```